# Change facecolor in text matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to change the text and the facecolor in a textbox that I have on a graph.

I create my text box like this :

```
props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='red', alpha=0.3)

ax.text(0.03, 0.97, 'test', transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=10, verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)
```

Changing the text is fine, I do :

```
ax.texts[-1].set_text('new text')
```

However I cannot find the command to change the color.

Basically I would like something like

```
ax.texts[-1].set_color('blue').
```

Comment: I found the solution. I use set_bbox(props)

Comment: I don't understand. The function you would "like to have", exists and works exactly like you apparently want it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by accessing the patch object associated with the text box.  I have found [this example](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html) helpful.

```
from pylab import subplot, show, draw
ax = subplot(111)
props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='red', alpha=0.3) 
t = ax.text(0.03, 0.97, 'test', transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=10, verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)
show()
bb = t.get_bbox_patch()
bb.set_facecolor('blue')
draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is simplier:

```
t = ax.text(0.03, 0.97, 'test', transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=10, verticalalignment='top', `bbox=dict(facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)`)
```

Simply putting in: `bbox=dict(facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)` in the ax.text statement changes the color.  I added the alpha to indicate that other attributes can also be changed.